How do you get the internal storage absolute path for the Android device in Kotlin Android Studio?
This is my question - How do you get the internal storage absolute path for the Android device in Kotlin Android Studio?
And I have searched the internet and found var gpath = Environment.getStorageDirectory().absolutePath
Ok, but that gives the SDCard storage.
And I have scanned the available methods in the Environment package. There are some that looked promising, like Environment.getRootDirectory()
But that only returns /storage
And even if I try .listFiles() on that it gives nothing.
I am just new to all this, so maybe there is a simple way to get there that I am missing.

I don't know how far you could go, but, there is no manual and direct way in code to access the root (/) folder of the Android device without special permissions or root.

You can check this link if you want more information about storage
https://source.android.com/docs/core/storage/scoped
I would recommend that if you need access to this folder for some reason, you try another approach.
